# Testing Node server (docker) with GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab

So I wrote a simple one-page server with node and express. I wrote a dockerfile for this and ran it locally. Then I made a postman collection and tested the endpoints.

I want to do this with gitlab ci using newman so I came up with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker build -t test_img .
  - docker run -d -p 3039:3039 test_img

stages:
  - test

# test

api-test:
  image: 
    name: postman/newman:alpine
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: test
  script:
    - newman run pdfapitest.postman_collection.json
```

It fails saying:

> docker build -t test_img .
>   /bin/sh: eval: line 86: docker: not found
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127

full output: https://pastebin.com/raw/C3mmUXKa

what am I doing wrong here? this seems to me like a very common use case but I haven't found anything useful about this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `api-test` job uses the image `postman/newman:alpine` to run the script.

This means that when GitLab tries to run the `before_script` section, it has no docker command available.

What you should do is to provide the `docker` command in the image you're using to run the job. You can do that either by installing docker as the first step of your script, or starting from a custom image which contains the software you're using inside the job plus the `docker` client itself.